# ShareKit 2.0 : How to access Flickr username

Tags: objective-c, flickr, sharekit

I am using ShareKit 2.0 to access Flickr. After logging in I wonder how I can access the username.
The ShareKit 2.0 says it should work like that:

```
NSString* uname = [SHK getAuthValueForKey:@"username" forSharer:@"SHKFlickr"];
```

Unfortunately this does not work, at least for me.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

The quick and dirty solution is the following:

(1) Create a singleton object in your project and have a member variable to store the user name
(2) Go to the class: ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Flickr/SHKFlickr.m
(3) In method *(void)flickrAPIRequest:(OFFlickrAPIRequest *)inRequest didCompleteWithResponse:(NSDictionary *)inResponseDictionary* line 291 you find the place where the flickr username is stored
(4) Store it in your singleton object and you will have access to it from all places

So for me this is enough but maybe you folks have some better solution?

Sven

Answer (score 1):

ShareKit is ready for this - SHKShareTypeUserInfo is the solution. Unfortunately it is implemented in Facebook and old (preiOS5) Twitter only at the moment. For Flickr and other OAuth services it needs to be coded. Would be nice, if you decide to implement it, to open a pull request...

More info on the matter is in [ShareKit's 2.0 Wiki FAQ](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/FAQ)